# On maven clean web project web services stops running

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven, spring-security

I am using Spring Security in my REST web services created using Spring/Hibernate, When i run the web services using Tomcat Apache in eclipse they works fine.
 Then I converted the project to maven form when I maven install the project and runs the web services on tomcat the web services works fine again. But when I maven-clean my project once and then maven-install & runs the web services on Tomcat web services does not work.
It throws :
`org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound` Exception.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Need more detail. And your question is ... ?

Comment: hi holmis83 i have edited the question

Comment: There is not enough information here to help you. Are your REST web services developed using Spring controllers? So you run 'mvn clean', then 'mvn install' and then you manually deploy the war file to a server? and what do you mean you launch a service? Need more info!!

Comment: Run in server, is that from within an IDE, and are mvn commands internal or external to the IDE?

Comment: Sorry for the incomplete information , i have edited it again.